# Qt QGraphicsView one background image on center

Tags: qt, qt4, qgraphicsview

My `QGraphicsView` item is a lot bigger than its background image, but I would like that background image to be drawn only once. Now the whole thing is filled with that background image as many times as there is space for it.

So, how can I force that background image to be drawn only once to the center of the view?

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
QPalette palette;
palette.setBrush(this->backgroundRole(),QBrush(*myImage));
this->setPalette(palette);
```

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

The `QGraphicsView` renders the background in the function `drawBackground()`. The default implementation of this fills the views rectangle using the background brush giving the result you are seeing.

You could override `drawBackground()` to render an image the way you want but that would mean subclassing `QGraphicsView`.

If this isn't an option, you could probably set a `QGraphicsPixmapItem` at the lowest Z order in the scene with the image you want.